# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python"

Tags: opencv, pip

I am struggling with Jetson TX2 board (aarch64).

I need to install python wrapper for OpenCV.

I can do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

But I cannot do:

```
$ sudo pip install opencv-python
```

Is this because there is no proper wheel file in http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv?

Is there a way to install opencv-python through pip?

Comment: Did the solution below work out for you?

Comment: @traducerad pip does not provide opencv-python for aarch64...

Comment: How did you solve it then?

Comment: put differently: How can you `import cv2` on the Jetson TX2?

Comment: @traducerad Easy. Compile OpenCV from its source. then just `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`.

Comment: I am affraid that this solution may give linking issues at one moment or another. Here is what solved it for me: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1023652/jetson-tx2/how-can-i-run-python-for-opencv-on-my-jetson-/post/5207956/#5207956
 :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pip` doesn't use http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, it downloads packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python).

The problem is that you have an unusual architecture; `pip` cannot find a package for it and there is no source code package.

Unfortunately I think you're on your own. You have to download source code from https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python, install compiler and necessary libraries and compile OpenCV yourself.

Answer (score 60):

We were getting the same error.For us, it solved by upgrading pip version (also discussed in [FAQ](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#frequently-asked-questions) of OpenCV GitHub). Earlier we had pip-7.1.0, post upgrading it to "pip-9.0.2", it successfully installed.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: You did a pip install of opencv-python on an nvidia jetson tx2?

Comment: This broke my Jetson TX2 i upgraded it and installed pip3 version 19.xx and pip3 doesnt work for me anymore. I am now re-flashing my jetson tx2

Comment: For me this did not work (pip 19.1.1 from /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
)

Answer (score 18):

Use this and it will work:

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: To upgrade pip the following command is suggested: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 10):

Another problem can be that the python version you are using is not yet supported by opencv-python.

E.g. as of right now there is no opencv-python for python 3.8. You would need to downgrade your python to 3.7.5 for now.

Comment: This was my issue. I had to downgrade.

Comment: Same for me: python 3.8.9 did not work (compatibility pb or a pb on my install?), whereas I could install opencv on python 3.7 or 3.10 (on conda virtual envs).

Answer (score 8):

It happened with me on Windows, pip was not able to install `opencv-python==3.4.0.12`.

Later found out that it was due to the Python version, Python 3.7 has some issue with not getting linked to https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python.

Downgraded to Python 3.6 and it worked with:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue but the mistake which I was making was `pip install python-opencv` where I should have used `pip install opencv-python`. Hope this helps to anyone. It took me few hours to find.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no proper wheel file in http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv?

Try this:(Worked in Anaconda Prompt or Pycharm)

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: opencv explicitly tells NOT to do that: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python#installation-and-usage

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to install Anaconda on your computer.

Then you should be able to do:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
conda install opencv
```

Comment: There's a [guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) from Anaconda showing how to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The first time I used the 32-bit version of python but my computer is 64-bit. I then reinstalled the 64-bit version and succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Install it by using this command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while using Python 3.9.0.
Upgrading python to latest version (currently 3.9.1) and reinstalling opencv-python solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and I solved it by simply *waiting*.

I had similar problem:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python (from versions: none)
```

Command `pip update` was not resolving my issue.
After lunch-time I tried again and it installed correctly the package.
Maybe the server was down.

Answer (score 0):

I update the version of python, and then the issue was addressed. Please refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQnpRbbEZB4