# Python version on RPI 3.8.2 but default is 3.5.3 issues

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have installed version 3.8.2 on my RPI because i previously had versions 2.7 and 3.5.3 installed. When I try to install stuff like ipython i get this: ERROR: Package 'ipython' requires a different Python: 3.5.3 not in '>=3.6'.

Tried various stuff and nothing works. Modified paths, installed 3.8.2 multiple times, tried to remove 3.5.3. Nothing works. It appareas the base version is 3.5 but I need it to be 3.8.2 and no idea how to do that.

Also when i try to run a python file I get the error that it cannot find numpy, and I have numpy installed in all versions.

Struggled for over a day to fix it and nothing. Can anybody help?

[versions of python on RPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwBlM.png)

Comment: Please check you environment variable e.g. `which python`. You have to adjust the path to the python version you want to use. Alternatively it is recommended to use an environment like miniconda and in there you can handle different versions of python more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a requirement of Debian, hence uninstalling the version present by default is not recommended (it basically breaks the system).

If you need to run python 3.8 you should install it manually and call it with

```sh
python3.8 what_you_need.py
```

Also for pip:

```sh
python3.8 -m pip install what_you_need
```

I also suggest you to have a look to virtual environments:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: Yes tried to run with python3.8, however i get the same two issues with numpy and ipython

Comment: Did you install the libraries for python3.8? (`python3.8 -m pip install what_you_need`)

Comment: It worked to install numpy, however when i try to install opencv i get this:     import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'. Tried installing it with sudo pip3 install opencv-python and says install is successful. Still not working

Comment: Did you try with `python3.8 -m pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: Yes, this is what i get: python3.8 -m pip install opencv-python

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python

Comment: Please check https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293933/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-opencv-python&ved=2ahUKEwij3tTEvIvoAhVxoFwKHRZRBtsQjjgwAHoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0P7ODk6Y2qEt2lwDQ3S0O4

Comment: A possible workaround is, if you can upgrade your RPI distro and your code is suitable for python3.7, to run a dist-upgrade. It will automatically install python3.7 and delete the legacy one.

Comment: ran a dist-upgrade and everything is up to date

Comment: Your system is not updated. I'm using RPI and it comes with python3.7. For full upgrade see: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Comment: Looked at the documentation, tried to update but everything is up to date. When i do sudo apt -y dist-upgrade i get: 

 File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-opencv (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-opencv
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: As I said in my answer, changing the version of Python breaks the system. I think you better format your RPI and restart with a fresh system.