# Error while installing OpenCV with Python3.9 on MacOS Mojave

Tags: opencv, python-3.9

Error message:

```
$ pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293933/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293933/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-opencv-python).

You have to download source code from https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python, install compiler and necessary libraries and compile OpenCV yourself.