# I can't install opencv-contrib-python with pip

Tags: python, opencv, pip

**Occured probrem**

I ran the following command to install an older version of [opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/4.0.0.21/#files) (4.0.0.21). Then an error occurred and this package could not be installed. How can I resolve this error?

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21
Collecting opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21 (from versions: 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 3.4.10.35, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34, 4.3.0.36, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21
```

**Environment**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.2
- Pip 19.2.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293933/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-opencv-python

Comment: This version work just with python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you specified `opencv-contrib-python (4.0.0.21)` does not have a relevant python3.8 version.

You need to use opencv corresponding to python3.8, or lower your python version to match the opencv version.